# How can I read the WebSEAL server address from request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, junction, webseal

I have a java enterprise application running on a websphere server. The application is only accessible through different webseal servers that do load balancing and authentication from different zones of the intranet.

- Intranet-URL: `https://webseal.intra/junction-old/ApplicationROOT`
- VPN-URL: `https://webseal.vpn/junction-old/ApplicationROOT`

Of course I can access the application directly as well: `https://server-old.intra/ApplicationROOT`.

The upcoming version of the application will be hosted at a new server. The application then is accessible through new junctions at the same webseal servers:

- Intranet-URL: `https://webseal.intra/junction-new/ApplicationROOT`
- VPN-URL: `https://webseal.vpn/junction-new/ApplicationROOT`

Of course there will be a new direct url as well: `https://server-new.intra/ApplicationROOT`

I now want to add an information page to the old application that provide new urls to the users. This page should re-direct to the new version. Since we have different webseals I will not hardcode one url in the re-direction. But when I try to read the request url with `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()` I only get the direct server address.

Is it possible to get the webseal address instead of the server address?

**Edit:**

I have some kind of solution, but I do not like it very much. It is more like a workaround. Currently I am using javascript to read the webeal's url and then perform a re-direct:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function redircetToNewUrl() {

            var port = window.location.port;
            if (port.length > 0) {
                port = ':' + port;
            } else {
                port = '';
            }

            var url = 'https://' + window.location.hostname + port + '/junction-new/ApplicationROOT';
            setTimeout(function f() {location.href = url;}, 30000);
        }
    </script>
    <BODY onload="redircetToNewUrl()">
```

It works fine, but, as I said, I don't like it very much.It would be better to create the re-direct url using java in the jsp.

Comment: The junctions can be configured to set request headers providing you with information.  For example, my junctions pass iv-remote-address and iv_server_name headers containing the IP address and server name respectively of the webseal server that forwarded the request.  There are likely more headers that webseal can send, but I do not have access to the webseal admin to confirm that or not.

Comment: @Palamino ^ that could probably be an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: How can I then read this fields? Is it HttpServletRequest#getSession().getAttribute()?

Comment: @Joko `getHeader()`